# How can I add a Source Generator as nuget reference?

Tags: c#, .net-5, sourcegenerators, csharp-source-generator

**How can I add an Source Generator to a C# net5 project as nuget package?**

To add a Project as Source Generator the following code does the job:

```xml
<ItemGroup>
  <ProjectReference Include="..\xyz.SourceGenerators\xyz.SourceGenerators.csproj"
    OutputItemType="Analyzer"
    ReferenceOutputAssembly="false"
    SetTargetFramework="TargetFramework=netstandard2.0" />
</ItemGroup>
```

However I'm looking for the XML `PackageReference` to add a nuget Package as Source Generator.

Comment: Just add it the same as any other package

Comment: @canton7 `<PackageReference Include="xyz.SourceGenerators" Version="1.0.0">` does not work for me. The Generator is not executed

Comment: Then something else is up: you're referencing it correctly

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65010453/how-to-pack-a-c-sharp-9-source-generator-and-upload-it-to-the-nuget, it might help you

Comment: @AlexandruClonțea you guessed correctly, the issue was a incorrect nuget package.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I worked out the solution. Thanks for your hints in the comments.

```xml
<PackageReference Include="xyz.SourceGenerators" Version="1.0.0">
```

is enough to add a Nuget package containing a source generator.

However you need to correctly add the Generator to the nuget package. To do this add the following lines to the `.csproj` of the nuget package.

```
<ItemGroup>
  <None Include="$(OutputPath)\netstandard2.0\$(AssemblyName).dll" Pack="true" PackagePath="analyzers/dotnet/cs" Visible="false" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Solution from: [How to pack a C# 9 source generator and upload it to the Nuget?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65010453/how-to-pack-a-c-sharp-9-source-generator-and-upload-it-to-the-nuget)